# Codeigniter Database Forge with multiple DB connections

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, expressionengine, dbforge

I use multiple DB connections in my Codeigniter application. When I load `dbforge` it loads it for the current db connection. How can I set dbforge so it work with the second DB connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EE1 it used to be:

```
mysql_select_db(<database name>);
```

or

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
...
mysql_close($conn);
```

I believe looking at example code elsewhere you can still use this approach.

**For EE2 try:**

```
$this->EE->load->dbforge();
$db = $this->EE->load->database(‘default’, TRUE);
```

Where the first parameter is looking for the database config settings group.

More info here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Examples of the old EE1 approach still working in EE2 here:
http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/213519/#992669